# How can I determine if two features, given a set of data, are the same feature or not?

Tags: distributions, correlation, confidence-interval, equivalence

Thanks in advance for the help.

Suppose I have a set of data of the form [feature, rating].  For the sake of argument lets assume feature can be movie A or movie B and rating is a ranked, continuous value on the interval [0,100].  Suppose also that the data set is very large.  In reality I have several more features but I intend to isolate each pair of features so I believe this is a comparable example (still one rating though).

Under the naive assumption that having equal ratings implies features are the same, how might I be able to determine if feature A and B are different or the same ( I acknowledge it may not be possible to determine either).  Given that I know the standard deviation of how ratings are assigned (suppose I have a user or set of users that assign the scores and I know the std of the ratings they give), how might I go about this?

I apologize if I put the wrong tags on this question, I'm not sure what this should go under.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is clustering.  That is a tag.

I would consider using a 1d gaussian mixture model to cluster on the ratings, and assume that when a particular point has higher probability of being from one member than any other, it is the same.

Moving ratings are horribly over-discretized, and are going to do a poor job of helping you classify things as being similar.

Links:

- http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/discriminant-analysis.html
- http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/cluster-analysis.html
- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clustering